# Face in French: visage, figure

Tags: vocabulaire

I have translated "face" into French. There is: "visage m", "figure f".

I am studying the difference between them.

- visage = "Face humaine, partie antérieure de la tête." - Larousse
- figure = "Partie antérieure de la tête ; face, visage." - Larousse

Hypothesis: "visage m" is more formal.

Am I right? What is the difference?

Answer (score 4):

Yes *visage* is more formal. It is used for example in a beauty salon (*soins du visage*) or in a medical context (*greffe du visage*.) No way for "*Soins de la figure*" or "*greffe de la figure*" to be used here.

On the other hand, kids are much more likely to say "*elle s'est peint la figure*" than "*elle s'est peint le visage*" and I would say to my kids "*lavez-vous la figure !*" definitely not "*lavez-vous le visage !*"

There are also *face*, *bouille*, *poire*, *faciès*, *gueule*, *portrait*, *trogne*, *trombine*…

Answer (score 3):

"Visage" is of more common use.

I guess the main difference is that "visage" refers expressly to the face as the front part of the head.

"Figure" have a more general meaning but it's still a perfectly acceptable translation for face. It sounds a bit outdated to me though. My grandma used to tell me "lave toi la figure" > "wash your face"

Other uses of "figure" (you cannot swap it for "visage" here):

**Une figure historique :** a historically important person, a person that was so important for an event / movement ... that it has come to embody it

**Une figure géométrique :** a geometrical shape like a circle, a square...

**Faire bonne figure :** to put on a brave face / avoid looking bad (even though you have reason to do so)

Comment: Visage et figure, comme synonymes: ça dépend à qui on parle, et le registre de langue Va te laver la figure! = Pour parler à des enfants, dans un registre familier. Elle fait très pâle figure = dans un registre très soutenu.